# How to make a function in Angular that does something every x seconds?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm doing a project in Angular 13 and I want to make an asynchronous function that connects to my API every x seconds. What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: RxJs interval operator.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the sample code which increments the value on every 5 seconds

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { interval } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  value = 0;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fnCall();
  }

  fnCall() {
    const i = interval(5 * 1000); // change timer value
    i.subscribe(() => {
      this.value += 1;
      console.log(this.value);
    });
  }
}
```